# Extract rows that have duplicates for certain column but are unique in another column

Tags: r, duplicates, unique

I'm am doing some coding in R. I would want to show the rows that have duplicates for columns ID and NAME but have different values for AGE.

For example I have this table:

```
ID |    NAME | AGE
111|     Mark| 22
222|     Anne| 21
333|    Chery| 30
444|    Megan| 16
555|  Charles| 37
111|     Mark| 23
222|     Anne| 22
333|    Chery| 30
111|     Mark| 22
```

As of now I have this code:

```
readfile <- read.csv(file='/home/user/shane/names.csv')
dat <- data.frame(ID=c(readfile$ID),NAME=c(readfile$NAME),AGE=c(readfile$AGE))
nam <- duplicated(dat[,c('ID','NAME)]) | duplicated(dat[,c('ID','NAME], fromLast = TRUE)
readfile[nam,]
```

The output looks like this:

```
ID |    NAME | AGE
111|     Mark| 22
222|     Anne| 21
333|    Chery| 30
111|     Mark| 23
222|     Anne| 22
333|    Chery| 30
111|     Mark| 22
```

**I would want the output to be:**

```
ID |    NAME | AGE
111|     Mark| 22
222|     Anne| 21
111|     Mark| 23
222|     Anne| 22
111|     Mark| 22
```

I would want to remove the columns with the ID = 333 as they have the same value in Age. would anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I'm confused. How do you reach the desired output? By filtering the original or the object where you filter out duplicates? There is no `ID=33`, only `333`.

Comment: Hi sorry if I am unclear. It would be the object where you have filtered out the duplicates. Then all Ages that are not consistent would be shown. for example if the ages on same id and name is 22,23,22. I would like these rows to be shown. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tweaked your code :)

```r
library(plyr) 

dat1 <- ddply(dat, .(ID, NAME, AGE), nrow) 
dat2 <- merge(dat1, dat, by=c("ID", "NAME", "AGE")) 
dat3 <- dat2[!(!duplicated(dat2[, 1:2], fromLast=T) & !duplicated(dat2[, 1:2])),] 
dat3[dat3$ID %in% dat3[dat3$V1 == 1, 1], 1:3]
```

**Output is:**

```
   ID NAME AGE
1 111 Mark  22
2 111 Mark  22
3 111 Mark  23
4 222 Anne  21
5 222 Anne  22
```

**Sample data:**

```
dat <- data.frame(ID=c(111,222,333,444,555,111,222,333,111), 
                  NAME=c('Mark','Anne','Chery','Megan','Charles','Mark','Anne','Chery','Mark'), 
                  AGE=c(22,21,30,16,37,23,22,30,22)) 
#   ID    NAME AGE
#1 111    Mark  22
#2 222    Anne  21
#3 333   Chery  30
#4 444   Megan  16
#5 555 Charles  37
#6 111    Mark  23
#7 222    Anne  22
#8 333   Chery  30
#9 111    Mark  22
```

**Update:** Corrected formatting for better reading

Comment: Thank you for this! just having some problems when I'm adding another row.  (ID=c(111,222,333,444,555,111,222,333,111), NAME=c('Mark','Anne','Chery','Megan','Charles','Mark','Anne','Chery','Mark'), AGE=c(22,21,30,16,37,23,22,30,22)). It would take out the two ids with 111 as the ages would be 22,23,22. only one of them is left and i would want all of them be included as they dont have a consistent age. Sorry i'm just new to R. Really appreciate all the help

Comment: `dat1 <- unique(dat[!(!duplicated(dat[,1:2], fromLast=T) & !duplicated(dat[,1:2])),]); 
dat1[!(!duplicated(dat1[,1]) & !duplicated(dat1[,1], fromLast = T)),]`

Comment: tried this but only 2 ids with 111 shows up. I intend to show the three 111s as they are not consistent. sorry if i'm being unclear. Thanks for helping.

    ID |    NAME | AGE
    111|     Mark| 22
    222|     Anne| 21
    111|     Mark| 23
    222|     Anne| 22
    111|     Mark| 22

Comment: Little lengthy sol but it should solve your requirement `dat <- data.frame(ID=c(111,222,333,444,555,111,222,333,111), NAME=c('Mark','Anne','Chery','Megan','Charles','Mark','Anne','Chery','Mark'), AGE=c(22,21,30,16,37,23,22,30,22));
library(plyr);
dat1 <- ddply(dat,.(ID,NAME, AGE),nrow);
dat2 <- merge(dat1,dat,by=c("ID","NAME","AGE"));
dat3 <- dat2[!(!duplicated(dat2[,1:2], fromLast=T) & !duplicated(dat2[,1:2])),];
dat3[dat3$ID %in% dat3[dat3$V1==1,1],1:3]`. I would request you to update your original question so that I can add it to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    group_by(ID, NAME) %>%
    filter(n() > 1, sum(duplicated(AGE)) == 0) %>%
    ungroup()
# A tibble: 4 x 3
     ID   NAME   AGE
  <dbl> <fctr> <dbl>
1   111   Mark    22
2   222   Anne    21
3   111   Mark    23
4   222   Anne    22
```

I used the data kindly provided by @Prem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, .SD[.N >1 & !sum(duplicated(AGE))], by = .(ID, NAME)]
#    ID NAME AGE
#1: 111 Mark  22
#2: 111 Mark  23
#3: 222 Anne  21
#4: 222 Anne  22
```